# Regex to match ASCII symbols / numbers

Tags: regex

For a bit of background, I use a word-filtering extension in my browser to remove ASCII emoticons, and it accepts Regex, but I'm having trouble getting the right formula that will filter ONLY emoticons and nothing else. I've tried all sorts of things but nothing seems to work in just the right way.

For example, trying to filter ":3", I've tried things like /(:3)/i, /(\b:3\b)/i, and even /^:3\s|\s:3\s|\s:3$/i, but each has their own issues. The first one filters :3 ANYWHERE, even if it's part of another word/phrase, the 2nd one doesn't seem to work at all, and the 3rd one only seems to work if there is a space before AND after the :3.

So if the input was something like:

text:3text

:3

text :3

The first line would be unaffected, but the :3 in the 2nd and 3rd lines would get filtered.

That's what I'm looking to do.

Comment: If you need to match `:3` as a whole word, use `/\B:3\b/`. Or if you need whitespace boundaries, `/(?:^|\s):3(?!\S)/m`

Comment: Oh. Well. That's a lot simpler than I had imagined!

Answer (score 0):

The `\b` word boundary when used before a non-word char requires a word char right before that char. `/\b:3\b/i` does not match in `text :3` because the space before `:` is not a word char.

You should use `\B`, a non-word boundary in such cases:

```
/\B:3\b/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vUhMYe/1).

If you plan to only match in between whitespace, use `/(?:^|\s):3(?!\S)/m`, where `(?:^|\s)` matches the start of a line or whitespace and `(?!\S)` requires end of string or a whitespace immediately to the right of the current location.